# Symbolic matrix equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am looking to a system of equations of the form $\pi =\pi P$, the one encountered in Markov chain theory.

My $P$ variable is:

```
mat = {{-(l0 + m0), l0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, -(l1 + l2 + m0), l1, l2, 0, 
1}, {0, m1, -(m1 + l2 + m0), 0, l2, 1}, {0, m2, 
0, -(m2 + l1 + m0), l1, 1}, {0, 0, m2, m1, -(m2 + m1 + m0), 1}};
mat // MatrixForm
```

My $\pi$ is defined through:

```
p = {{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}};
```

And I used solve as:

```
Solve[p.mat == {{-(l0 + m0) p, 1}}, Flatten@p]
```

Is my code correct? I find a {} in the output. Is Mathematica unable to process?

Answer (score 3):

Several syntax errors corrected. You should try to get a better grip on the syntax:

```
mat = {{-(l0 + m0), l0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
         {0, -(l1 + l2 + m0), l1, l2, 0, 1}, 
         {0, m1, -(m1 + l2 + m0), 0, l2, 1}, 
         {0, m2, 0, -(m2 + l1 + m0), l1, 1}, 
         {0, 0, m2, m1, -(m2 + m1 + m0), 1}}; 
p = {p1, p2, p3, p4,  p5};
Solve[p.mat == Join[-(l0 + m0) p, {1}]]
```

(hint) Also, try to explore other alternatives for solving equation systems

Comment: Thanks. I have a small issue here. I need to solve for the vector $p$. How do I specify that? Solve[p.mat == Join[-(l0 + m0) p, {1}],p,Reals] gives me {}.

Comment: @Bravo Try `Reduce[p.mat == Join[-(l0 + m0) p, {1}], {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}]`

Answer (score 1):

First, it's more convenient to work with true vectors than $1\times n$ or $n\times 1$ matrices ("row vectors" and "column vectors"), so I'm going to rewrite things in that form.

```
p = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}
```

Now we can solve like this:

```
Solve[Append[-(l0 + m0) p, 1] == p.mat, p]

(* ==> {} *)
```

We get `{}` which means that there's no solution.  What Mathematica means that there's no solution in general, for arbitrary values of the `l0`, `m0`, etc. parameters.  But there may be solutions if those parameters satisfy certain conditions.  To get a *full* solution, including these conditions, either use `Reduce`, or change the [`MaxExtraConditions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MaxExtraConditions.html) option in `Solve`:

First, let's try `MaxExtraConditions -> Automatic` to generate the fewest possible conditions:

```
Solve[Append[-(l0 + m0) p, 1] == p.mat, p, MaxExtraConditions -> Automatic]

Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>

{{p1 -> ConditionalExpression[1 - p2 - (l1 p2)/m1 - (l2 p2)/m2 - (l1 l2 p2)/(m1 m2), l0 == 0], 
  p3 -> ConditionalExpression[(l1 p2)/m1, l0 == 0], 
  p4 -> ConditionalExpression[(l2 p2)/m2, l0 == 0], 
  p5 -> ConditionalExpression[(l1 l2 p2)/(m1 m2), l0 == 0]}}
```

This only gives solutions for four of the variables in terms of the fifth.  You can ask `Solve` to generate more conditions to obtain more solutions.

---

Most likely you already know that your parameters must satisfy certain conditions.  The best solution would be to specify these conditions together with the equations to let `Solve`/`Reduce` know about them, and give appropriate solutions.